# Suppress onChange and only use onBlur to a React input component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called `Test` that receives 2 props: `CurrentPage` and `OnPageRequest: (currentPage: number) => void`

When the parent component uses `Test`, it sets the Current page number in its state. As you update, the input field below, that value gets fed back up to the parent component via the `OnPageRequest` as:

`OnPageRequest(e.target.value);`

wherein return, the parent component updates its current page number in the state.

Test component:

```
const handlePageNumberBlur = (e) => {
    OnPageRequest(e.target.value);
}

render() {
    return (
        <input
            title="Current Page"
            onBlur={handlePageNumberBlur}
            aria-label="Current Page"
            min="1"
            max={TotalPages}
            placeholder="1"
            type="number"
            value={this.props.CurrentPage} />
    )
}
```

I'm trying to write `Test` in such a way so that it only fires back the newly inputted value only when the `onBlur` event is triggered. But I've learned that with the above code, it never updates the `value`. It only does it if I have an `onChange` event where I do: `OnPageRequest(e.target.value);`

How can I get it to change only when onBlur fires?

SAMPLE: https://codesandbox.io/s/kumuc

Comment: Not sure if that's related but I think this issue can help you with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832389/updating-a-react-input-text-field-with-the-value-on-onblur-event

Comment: how input value will update if you don't have `onChange` as your input in controlled? and if input value is not updated, your `handlePageNumberBlur` function will receive same value everytime.

Comment: Is it possible  to share your code in a code sandbox?

Comment: @A.K.47 I've updated the initial post with a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `defaultValue` instead of `value`. The `defaultValue` prop only sets the value to the input on initial render and you won´t need to keep it updated if the value of the prop changes.

```
<input
    { ... }
    defaultValue={this.prop.CurrentPage}
/>
```

But this can also be an issue if you set `CurrentPage` after the input has rendered, which depends on where you get your initial value for the prop.

If you need to keep the input updated after the first render, you can update its value using [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.inputRef.current.value != this.props.CurrentPage) {
            this.inputRef.current.value = this.props.CurrentPage;
        }
    }

    /* ... */

    render() {
        return <input 
            { ... }
            defaultValue={this.props.CurrentPage}
            ref={this.inputRef}
        />
    }
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't update the value if I don't set the onChange

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You can´t set `value` and `defaultValue` at the same time. Try removing the `value` prop.

Comment: Okay I've implemented a solution. Would appreciate if you can have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/kumuc

Comment: Works as intended. The input can be edited and only on blur there is a console message.

Comment: It looks like even if I take out the `useEffect`, it still functions as intended. Why is that?

Comment: That is thanks to the `defaultValue` prop. The `value` prop always overwrites the value of the `input`, that also includes changes by the user. That is why there has to be an `onChange` handler. But with `defaultValue` the `input` manages the value itself, because React only overrides the value of the input on the first render.

Comment: Ah okay. Is that why when I inspect the element, the `value` gets overwritten every time the onBlur fires? Basically, its passing the value up to the parent component that again sets the defaultValue?

Comment: No. `defaultValue` only is being set once, even if it is updated. The element just keeps its value because React is not overwriting it as it is the default behaviour when using the `value` prop. I recommend you read up on the thematic of [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).